# Crontab command stops after 25 mins but runs perfectly on terminal

Tags: php, cron, execution-time

I have set the execution time for a PHP script at the start of the file as follows:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 18000);
```

I want this PHP script to be executed daily on crontab. But the script stops the execution after 25 minutes.
However, this is not the case when I execute the command manually on the putty terminal. When executed on the terminal the script runs perfectly till the end.

This is an integration script and it takes 2-3 hours for complete execution and is required to be executed daily. So needs to add it to the cron. 
Following is the cron command.

```
0 6 * * * php /var/www/html/filename function_name 2>&1 | tee -a /var/www/html/output.txt
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: *Why* does the program stop? There are several possibilities there, the most likely being a permission or limit problem. Are you running the script with the same user as PuTTY's? Is there any hint in the output log?

Comment: The program stops without any error and exactly after 25 minutes. The user for cron and Putty is same i.e root. Neither output file(output.txt) nor cron log file is showing any error

Comment: Is there any hint in the system log? Max execution time is already 0 in the CLI, you shouldn't need to override. If the log doesn't help, I fear the only recourse is to `strace` either the script or cron itself.

Comment: No any error messages in any files... Any changes that need to be done on server side?

Comment: Until we know why the file stops (or is being stopped), we'd just be shooting in the dark. I'd start adding logging echos to the script, specifying time and get_memory_usage. Meanwhile, run instead a cron job doing only `sleep(60)` sixty times. See whether *that* gets stopped after 25 minutes. This should tell you whether it's something that stops the script, or the script that blows itself. Also, try running the script at 05:50. If it stops after **thirty** five minutes, you'll know that there's something happening at 06:25 that's interfering. Without knowing more, that's all we can do.

Comment: Thanks. I have already done script debugging through which I found that the script stops after 25 minutes. Will follows the other methods you have suggested. Will update if I found anything through them. Thanks once again.